# Int64 usage in recursive functions

Tags: recursion, integer, ocaml, int64

I have the following code written in Ocaml to try and generate the first 50 [catalan](https://oeis.org/A000108) [numbers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiyv8WlrbL8AhU57zgGHd1qAMYQFnoECA4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCatalan_number&usg=AOvVaw06wnsic-EIkHKRh94VEIxs):

```ocaml
let rec f n:int64=
 if n<1 then 1L
 else (4*n-2)*f((n-1L))/(n+1L)
;;
for i = 0 to 50 do
  Printf.printf "%d\n"(f i)
done;
```

But the problem is that the recursion function doesn't seem to accept `Int64` values and seems to want `Int` instead despite me notating `n` as `int64`:

```
File "/proc/self/fd/0", line 3, characters 19-21:
3 |  else (4*n-2)*f((n-1L))/(n+1L)
                       ^^
Error: This expression has type int64 but an expression was expected of type
         int
exit status 2
```

Is there a way to ensure I can int64 numbers here with recursion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't recursion *per se*, it's that the operators in OCaml are strongly typed. So the `-` operator is of type `int -> int -> int`.

Without getting into lots of fussing with the syntax, the easiest fix is probably to use the named functions of the Int64 module. You can use `Int64.sub` rather than `-`, for example.

You can use the notation `Int64.(... <expr> ...)` to avoid repeating the module name. If you rewrite your code this way, you get something like this:

```
let rec f (n : int64) : int64 =
    Int64.(
        if n < 1L then 1L
        else
            mul (sub (mul 4L n) 2L)
                (f (div (sub n 1L) (add n 1L)))
    )
```

Looking at the results computed by this function, they don't look  like Catalan numbers to me. In fact the 50th Catalan number is too large to be represented as an int64 value.
So there is still some work to do. But this is how to get past the problem you're seeing (IMHO).

If you really want to work with such large numbers, you probably want to look at the [Zarith module](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/zarith).

Comment: Thanks! Hmm strange but with the loop im using in my code, it seems I can't make `i` int64 (as the function requires it), despite doing `Int64.i`, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Using `Int64.xxx` allows you to access the named values defined in the Int64 module. The value `1` is not one of these. So you wouldn't expect it to work. The way to represent 1 in type int64 is `1L` (as you have in your code).

Comment: No I mean the variable `i` in my loop

Comment: Oh I'm sorry but is there no other way to produce such large numbers without using any modules?

Comment: You can write your own multi-precision integer functions. That is probably not too hard if they don't have to be fast. Otherwise, I'd say no.

Comment: The `for` statement only works for `int`. You should use an index of type `int` and convert it to `int64` when calling your function. To convert use `Int64.of_int`.

Answer (score 1):

Submitted as an additional suggestion to Jeffrey's answer: whether using `Int64` or `Zarith`, you might create a module defining arithmetic operators and then locally open that to clean up your code.

E.g.

```
module Int64Ops =
struct
  let ( + ) = Int64.add
  let ( - ) = Int64.sub
  let ( * ) = Int64.mul
  let ( / ) = Int64.div
end

let rec f n =
  Int64Ops.(
    if n < 1L then 1L
    else (4L * n - 2L) * f (n - 1L) / (n + 1L)
  )
```

Or you could use a functor to make it easier to work with multiple different types of numbers.

```
module type S =
sig
  type t
  val add : t -> t -> t
  val sub : t -> t -> t
  val mul : t -> t -> t
  val div : t -> t -> t
end

module BasicArithmeticOps (X : S) = 
struct
  type t = X.t
  let ( + ) = X.add
  let ( - ) = X.sub
  let ( * ) = X.mul
  let ( / ) = X.div
end
```

```
# let module A = BasicArithmeticOps (Float) in
A.(8. + 5.1);;
- : float = 13.1
# let module A = BasicArithmeticOps (Int) in
A.(8 + 3);;
- : int = 11
# let module A = BasicArithmeticOps (Int64) in
A.(4L + 3L);;
- : int64 = 7L
```